# Lumen Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, lumen-5.2

Just can't get the Lumen authentication to work at all.

I have a fresh install and trying to follow the docs here:

https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication

I've Uncommented the `AuthProvider` line in the `app.php` file (along with everything else, facade, etc). Then in a simple controller I just do `dd(Auth::use())`.

I just can't get around this error:

```
Undefined index: provider
in AuthManager.php line 152
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}('8', 'Undefined index: provider', '/home/vagrant/Code/gryd/api.gryd.com/vendor/illuminate/auth/AuthManager.php', '152', array('name' => 'api', 'config' => array('driver' => 'token'))) in AuthManager.php line 152
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Since someone asked for a code sample.

1. Install Lumen
2. Uncomment everything in app.php
3. Put this in routes:

   $app->get('/api/v1/users/{id}', function () {
       dd(\Auth::user());
   });

Comment: And your code is ...?

Comment: There is no code, it's fresh Lumen install, just put `Auth::user()` in the controller.

Comment: Try this http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28928192/Lumen-Authentication-unknown-index-provider.html I'm seriously surprised people need hacks like this... Also the installer is bugged if you try to install alongside laravel. Very dissapointed in that.

Comment: Well that's kind of a deal breaker. Now I'm worried it's just going to be one issue after another. Pretty crazy to just get errors like this out of the box.

Comment: Just realized in the error that it's looking for a `token` driver so I changed `Auth::viaRequest('api', functi` to `Auth::viaRequest('token', funct` which seems to work. I guess the question remains, how to change the auth driver via `.env` And why on earth would they default it to an error...strange.

Comment: I have just created a PR that addresses this issue. Should be accepted shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I still haven't found out how to change the api request type via `.env`. But for now switching it to `token` seems to work.

Changed `Auth::viaRequest('api', functi` to `Auth::viaRequest('token', funct`.

Comment: I tried this but did'nt work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697095/lumen-5-3-authentication

Answer (score 8):

This is what I've got so far, which is working but not quite how I'd like it. The following works for Token-based auth, which is the default setting in Lumen.

#### Enable Authentication

Register `routeMiddleware` and `AuthServiceProvider` by un-commenting the following lines in `bootstrap/app.php`.

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
]);
```

and

```
$app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
```

#### Configuration

Copy `vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/auth.php` to `config/auth.php`. Create the root `config` folder if you have to.

Inside we will find four items (`defaults`, `guards`, `providers`, `passwords`). We're concerned with the first three.

First we name the default **guard** as ABC.

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => env('AUTH_GUARD', 'ABC'),
],
```

Next we define the ABC guard with `token` as its **driver** and `XYZ` as its **provider**.

```
'guards' => [
    'ABC' => [
        'driver' => 'token', 
        'provider' => 'XYZ'
    ],
],
```

And the XYZ provider is defined with `eloquent` as the **driver** and `App\User::class` as the **model**.

```
'providers' => [
    'XYZ' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\User::class,
    ],
],
```

#### Completing Setup

Finally, we use the `auth` middleware in our routing setup, as usual.

```
$app->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () use ($app) {
```

---

So this is what gets the token auth up and running. It uses the `api_token` field in the users table to authenticate, which can be found in `TokenGuard`.

I still haven't found out what effect `AuthServiceProvider` and `$this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {` have on my app yet.

Comment: what if I want to use env variable instead of eloquent, what possibly can be my providers configuration look like???