# Lumen 5.3 Authentication

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, lumen

I have installed Lumen and trying to implement authentication.

I am using Laravel Framework version Lumen (5.3.3) (Laravel Components 5.3.*).

In app.php I have uncommented the following.

```
$app->withFacades();

$app->routeMiddleware([
     'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
 ]);

$app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
```

In `\app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot() {
        $this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
            if ($request->input('api_token')) {
                return User::where('api_token', $request->input('api_token'))->first();
            }
        });
}
```

Here when I debugged, `viaRequest` method is not getting executed.

Comment: have you define the auth middleware at your roure?

Comment: Kiren Siva could you solve this problem? The same thing happens to me and I have no idea how to solve it. I have enabled the middleware in the path through a group and I have uncommented everything in `bootstrap\app.php`

Comment: $request->header('api_token') and send your through header

Answer (score 1):

Did you define your route as follow:

```
$app->get('endpoint', ['middleware' => 'auth', function () { /* some code */ }]);
```

assigning the Auth middleware to a route.